# Laravel Cashier one subscription to all product plans

Tags: php, laravel, billing, laravel-cashier

Stripe has recently released a new toolset called Billing. https://stripe.com/billing  
I have created a new product, of which there are 3 plans. I am able to use the Stripe SDK to create a single subscription to all 3 plans for the product. I would like to use Laravel Cashier to do the same but I am either missing how to do this or it is not currently possible.

With the Stripe SDK I can do something like:

```
$stripeSubscription = StripeSubscription::create(array(
    self::PARAM_SUBSCRIPTION_CUSTOMER => $customer,
    self::PARAM_SUBSCRIPTION_ITEMS => $subscriptionItems
), array(
    self::PARAM_API_KEY => $this->getStripeKey()
));
```

Where `$subscriptionItems` is an array of plans for a given product.  
Within the Laravel Cashier Billable trait, this method is used for subscribing:

```
public function newSubscription($subscription, $plan)
{
    return new SubscriptionBuilder($this, $subscription, $plan);
}
```

As far as I am aware this will create a new subscription to a single plan, requiring 3 subscriptions per user. I would like to create a single subscription where all 3 pricing plans are within it, using the Billable trait.

Comment: Could you share some code explaining what you've tried and specifically where you think you are needing help?